# Alfred Action to open set of possible actions

Tags: macos, alfred

I have custom Alfred workflow to `File Filter` some folders of my choice. I have two actions - to browse with Alfred, and, with CMD modifier, to open in Sublime.

I want to have an action where I may choose which program I want to open it in. I use 2-3 programs for basic editing, so I want to be able to select one of these.

Workflow would be:

- start my workflow
- enter few chars to find file
- select a file with CMD
- choose editor of choice from the list

How to implement the last thing? In other words, how to implement incremental actions e.g. "do this with this and then this".

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways to do it.

- Because you can choose [which application will be used to open the file instead of the default one](http://support.alfredapp.com/workflows:config:actions-open-file). A simple idea is using different keyword for each application. e.g. `vim [file-name]` for `vim` while `sublime [file-name]` for `sublime`.
- Another way is using `Run Script` instead of `Open File`. An Apple script or Bash script can get the result in `File Filter` and open different application as you wish.